# Objective-C costum drawing with draw: (CGContextRef *)context

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a home work which our professor told us to make circle, square, and triangle confirm to a protocol called

`Shape.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol Shape <NSObject>

@required
- (void)draw:(CGContextRef) context;
- (float)area;

@end
```

and use `UIBotton` to call different class to draw..

I call the draw function from my view controller

`XYZController.m`:

```
- (IBAction)rectButton:(id)sender {
    CGRect frame = [myView bounds];

    MyRect *rectView = [[MyRect alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [rectView draw: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    [myView addSubview:rectView];
}
```

where `myView` is a `UIView` I dragged onto `.xib`

and perform draw in `MyRect` class

`MyRect.h`:

```
@interface MyRect : UIView <Shape>
```

I changed the super class from NSObject to UIView... Not sure if I did it correctly..

`MyRect.m`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)draw : (CGContextRef) context
{
    CGRect bounds = [self bounds];

    CGRect originRect = CGRectMake(25.0, 25.0, 50.0, 75.0);

    CGContextAddRect(context, originRect);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, originRect);
}
```

But then I got the error:

```
[...] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
[...] <Error>: CGContextAddRect: invalid context 0x0
[...] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
```

I guess it's from `[rectView draw: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`

Any idea of how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would first of all overwrite the `-drawRect:` method in your MyRect class.
And then use

```
[[UIColor greenColor] set] // or setStroke, 'cause your using stroke and not fill!
CGContextStrokeRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect)
```

You should use `-drawRect:` and make all drawing in your UIView subclass. You can **not** get the context from where you want. Only in the named method.

Comment: Thanks, but not sure if our professor did it on purpose (he makes mistakes often..), he ask us to overwrite `- (void)draw:(CGContextRef) context;`
If discarding my code, what do you think you can do to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no `-draw:` method in UIKit. You could possibly use CALayer Delegate and overwrite CALayers `-drawInContext:` method, but you'd only need this if you want to animate the rect.

Comment: To solve the problem you'll only need to put my code above into the named `-drawRect:` method, thats it. It will be called automatically and you don't have to call `[rectView drawRect:] or something. No further magic required ;)

Comment: I have tested and it works.. But I don't think I will get points 'cause he asked us to use delegate to confirm to `Shape.h` and draw rectangles and stuff.. Since `draw:` is a requirement, I assumed he wanted us to use that method to draw...

Comment: I'm not pretty sure how this could work 'cause the views context is only available in this method. You could easily use a BOOL to confirm if it should draw or not. In your custom `-draw` method you then do this: `shouldDraw = YES; [self setNeedsDisplay]; shouldDraw = NO;` This will force your view to redraw.

Comment: But the way the Shape protocol is defined, it will never work. You cannot pass a CGContextRef here unless you create MyRect in the superViews `-drawRect:` method. But this won't make any sense :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right :p Our professor does stuffs that don't really make sense sometimes :)
Anyway, thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: You are welcome! Please report again when your prof said something about it and what the result was :)

Comment: Just a quick update, it turns out our professor wanted us to add another view (let's say myView) and call `-drawRect:` from there and send the context from myView to square or circle by calling `-draw:(CGContextRef *)`! :)

Answer (score 1):

UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() will return nil except in drawRect:. UIKit will create context before drawRect:.

Also you can create your own context to draw.

UIKit example:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() 
UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() to get image context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Core graphic example:

```
CGBitmapContextCreate()
```

Documents:

[UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

[CGBitmapContext Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I'm reading the documents and wording how I can get `CGSize` if I want it to be the `UIView`'s size (myView)?